# Space separated text to vector in R

Tags: regex, r

I have a vector initial

```
initial<-paste("A,B","C,D","E,F",sep=" ")
```

and the final vector I want is

```
final<-c("A,B","C,D","E,F")
```

How can I achieve this in R?

Also if the spaces are non uniform like this

```
"A,B   C,D  E,F"
```

how should it be handled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `strsplit()` for this.  For a possible one or more spaces we use `\\s+` for our split value. Then since `strsplit()` returns a list the length of it's first argument, we can drop in back to a character vector with the "subset"  `[[1]]`.

```
strsplit(initial, "\\s+")[[1]]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is another option:

```
scan(text=initial, what='')
# [1] "A,B" "C,D" "E,F"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two [`stringi`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringi/index.html) options.  The first is essentially the same as the `strsplit` approach, and the second uses bytewise pattern matching instead of regex, and discards empty splits (to handle variable numbers of spaces between splits).

```
library(stringi)

# same as the strsplit approach
stri_split_regex(initial, "\\s+")[[1]]


stri_split_fixed(initial, " ", omit_empty = TRUE)[[1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the best answer but for fun we could extract terms meeting char,char pattern followed by a space or end of string:

```
initial<-paste("A,B","C,D","E,F",sep=" ")

library(stringi)
stringi::stri_extract_all_regex(initial, "[^,],[^,](?=(\\s|$))")
```